# how to restrict user with another id to update other user comment in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
public function update (Request $request, $id, $commentid) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'body' =>'required|max:255'
    ]);

    $post = Post::findorFail($id);
    $comment = Comment::find($commentid);

    $body = $request->body;
    $comment->post_id = $post->id;
    $comment->body = $body;
    $comment ->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $comment ->save();
    return response()->json(['data' => $comment], 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

how to restrict other `user->id` to update `auth->id` comment 
and use select method of post to catch `user_id` of particular post but getting  errorexception 
and used middleware but still error is same

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you can try do it this way:

```
public function update (Request $request, $id, $commentid) {
  $comment = Comment::find($commentid);

  if ( Auth::user()->id !== $comment->user_id ) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Forbidden'], 403);
  }

  // other code
}
```

I hope, this decision is enough for you, but I have to say that I prefer abstract validation and rights-check logic into `FormRequest`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation

In `rules()` function you can set your validation rules.
In `authorize()` check whether user can change comment.

Answer (score 0):

you're using Auth::user(); to authorized to user. it's laravel default functionality to authentication a user